# How to change this specific SSH message?

Tags: ssh, debian, vps

So I've been using these servers from privex which are great but on login they have a default message as shown in the photo below. I was curious how to change this? I've been researching it for a little while, and I know about /etc/banner and motd and everything like that, but it's not located at all in any of those regular files. Is this something the provider does on their end that isn't possible to change from the VPS? This is debian 11 btw.

The only part I can edit that IS part of MOTD is the bottom part that says "The programs included with the Debian...." etc. However, I want to edit the "Privex Servers" text.

[image: SSH Login Message screenshot]

Comment: Any chance you can find some clue by running a command like `grep -R "Thank you for purchasing" /etc`?

Comment: Edit files in /etc/motd/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps check ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile for any customizations that they may have added through that?